# Can a partially applied function be extracted or interrogated for the applied parameter value

Tags: scala

Is there a way to extract or interrogate a partially applied function to get the applied value.
For example, can the value 3 be extracted from reduceBy3 in the code below.

```
def subtract(x:Int, y:Int) = x-y
val reduceBy3 = subtract(3,_:Int)
```

I have experimented with creating an extractor has shown in the example below however the unapply method must accept an (Int=>Int) function that requires interrogation.

```
class ReduceBy(y: Int) {
  val amt = y
  def subtract(y: Int, x: Int) = x - y
}

object ReduceBy extends Function1[Int, Int => Int] {
  def apply(y: Int) = {
    val r = new ReduceBy(y)
    r.subtract(y, _: Int)
  }
  def unapply(reduceBy: ReduceBy): Option[Int] = Some(reduceBy.amt)
}

object ExtractPartialApplied extends App {
  val r3 = ReduceBy(3)
  val extract = r3 match {
    case ReduceBy(x) => ("reduceBy", x)
    case x: ReduceBy => ("reduceBy", x.amt)
    case _ => ("No Match", 0)
  }

  println(extract)
  val z = r3(5)
  println(z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `subtract` method receive the first parameter, and then return a function-like object which will then take the second parameter, similarly to a multiple-argument-list function, but which you can then extend however you wish.

This doesn't look very elegant though, and needs a bit of manual boilerplate.

```
class ReduceBy(val amt: Int) {
  def subtract(x: Int) = {
    val xx = x // avoid shadowing
    new Function[Int, Int] {
      def x = xx
      def apply(y: Int) = x - y
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution adapting the answer by danielkza is to have the companion object do the extraction and return a ReduceBy function that holds onto the the initial value.

```
object ReduceBy {
  def apply(y: Int) = new ReduceBy(y) 
  def unapply(reduceBy: ReduceBy): Option[Int] = Some(reduceBy.amt)
}    

class ReduceBy(val amt: Int) extends Function[Int, Int] {
  def apply(y: Int) = y - amt
} 

object ExtractPartialApplied extends App {
  val reduceBy3 = ReduceBy(3)
  val extract = reduceBy3 match {
    case ReduceBy(x) => ("ReduceBy(x)", x)
    case x: ReduceBy => ("ReduceBy", x.amt)
    case _ => ("No Match", 0)
  }
  println(extract)
  println(reduceBy3(5))
}
```